# Why is "%appdata%" "AppData\Roaming"

Tags: windows

Why is `%appdata%` `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming` and not just `C:\Users\<user>\AppData`?

And whats the difference between `AppData\LocalLow` and `AppData\Local`?

Related, but no duplicate: [What is "%AppData%"?](https://superuser.com/questions/632891/what-is-appdata)

Comment: As Ramhound commented, three's no way we can tell you "why" MS chose that.  As for the other part of the question, check out the duplicate I'm about to mark this as.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. Poster appears to be asking why the *convention* is the way it is, i.e. why default to roaming? That is, why have `%appdata%` -> `AppData\Roaming`, and `%localappdata%` -> `AppData\Local`; as opposed to `%appdata%` or  `%localappdata%` -> `AppData\Local`, and `%roamingappdata%` -> `AppData\Roaming`? No comment on whether that's answerable, though.