# Why doesn't Discord install to Program Files on Windows?

Tags: installation, discord

Why doesn't Discord installed to the usual Windows folders of `C:\Program Files` or `C\Program Files (x86)`? If it's not in Program Files, where does it install to?

Comment: In general to be able to answer these type of questions by yourself I recommend installing [Everything](http://alternativeto.net/software/everything/). There you can quickly search for all files on your machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Windows, Discord is installed to `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Discord`. You find it by entering `%localappdata%\Discord` in the Windows Explorer path bar.

[As for *why* Discord installs to AppData](https://twitter.com/discordapp/status/843624938674311168)...

> It's because we use the Squirrel Installer, it doesn't offer much
>   customization, we're working on our own custom installer.

---

***Note:*** Currently it is not possible to change Discord's default installation location, despite being a [fairly popular request](https://feedback.discordapp.com/forums/326712-discord-dream-land/suggestions/10552038-allow-us-to-change-the-installation-location).

Comment: Does discord need admin rights to install? I'd guess the need for that is what they're trying to get around, for an application they feel only one user per system will use

Comment: Related: [What is “%AppData%”?](https://superuser.com/q/632891/358766)

Comment: I can confirm that Discord is currently able to be installed without admin rights.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't get this reasoning. If you're the only one on PC - you DO have admin, and if you have several users, then why do you feel only one will ever use voice chat? Both job-communication related or family gaming PC all fit "everyone will use it" profile. I hate this idiotic trend of "lets shit over all HDD space with dozens of copies of same thing" popularized by Chrome (on that note I hate having dozens of copies of CEF into single account too).

Comment: is there a reason to why it still hasn't existed the response was from 2017. I know their teams are always busy cleaning up the program with great updates, I'd figure letting people pick where to install would be a nice one.